# Is there a ring such that the nilradical of it is not nilpotent?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Example of a ring such that the nilradical of it is not nilpotent. Please help me.

Comment: What have you tried so far? **To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far**. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people are much more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself.

Comment: @Zev Chonoles I know that in a Noetherian ring the nil radical is nilpotent. Also, in a Artinian ring. Indeed, the ring is commutative with identity.

Comment: Do you know examples of non-Noetherian rings? Can you modify those examples so they have lots of nilpotents? Look at my answer for a hint.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:**

- The nilradical of $k[x]/(x^2)$ is the ideal $N=(x)$, and $N^2=(0)$, so $N$ is a nilpotent ideal.
- The nilradical of $k[x,y]/(x^2,y^2)$ is the ideal $N=(x,y)$, and $N^3=(0)$, so $N$ is a nilpotent ideal.
- ...

Comment: So consider $Z[x_{1},x_{2},...]$. Is it true?

Comment: The ring $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,x_2,\ldots]$ doesn't have any nilpotents; you need to take a quotient. Look again at how the rings were formed in my hint.

Answer (score 9):

Take the polynomial ring $R=\mathbb K[x_i \mid i \in \mathbb N]$ in infinitely many variables. Then take the ideal $I=(x_i^i \mid i \in \mathbb N)$. The ring $R/I$ has for each $i \in \mathbb N$ a nilpotent element $\bar x_i$ which has nilpotence index $i$. In this ring the nilradical contain for each $i \in \mathbb N$ the element $\bar x_i$, but for every $k \in \mathbb N$ we have that $\bar x^k_{k+1} \ne 0$ is an element of the $k$-th power of the nilradical. 
So the nilradical isn't nilpotent.